# MySQL General Error 2031

Tags: mysql, pdo

I keep getting:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 ' in XXXXX
```

The code I'm using is:

```
$CR = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entities  WHERE (entities.typeId = 2 OR entities.typeId = 1)');
$count = $CR->fetchColumn();
```

I have tried using prepare instead but I get the same result.

Any idea what's causing this and how I can fix it?

```
class Database extends PDO {
    function __construct($user = 'xxx', $pass = 'xxx', $database = 'abc', $host = 'xxx', $port = 'xxx')
    {
            parent::__construct('mysql:host=' . $host . ';port=' . $port . ';dbname=' . $database, $user, $pass);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, FALSE);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, TRUE);
            $this->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
    }
}
$this->db = new Database();
```

Comment: $this->db is not a raw pdo instance, isn't it?

Comment: @Your Common Sense It is an extension, I have edited my post to show it.

Comment: Error 2031 is "no data supplied for parameters in prepared statement" but the SQL query you show doesn't have any parameter placeholders. I guess your actual query is different, or else you posted the wrong error code.

Answer (score -4):

try to remove:

$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, FALSE);